# Event causes exception due to missing resource

Tags: winforms, exception, events, resources, c++-cli

My form has 96 check boxes, 4 DataGridView controls, and some other controls.  Everything works fine until I add an event to the fourth DataGridView.  When I add any event to that control, the code builder adds a resource that compiles but causes a run time exception.  The exception is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.

I ran a Diff between the code that works and the code that causes the exception.  When I add the event to the DataGridView control, the code below is added to my MainForm.h file.

```
System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
```

Each of the checkbox controls have a line as shown below that wasn't there before adding the event to the DataGridView.

```
resources->ApplyResources(this->checkBox_D1, L"checkBox_D1");
```

The code builder deleted the code below from each checkbox after adding the event.

```
this->checkBox_D1->AutoSize = true; 
this->checkBox_D1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 19); 
this->checkBox_D1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(40, 17);
this->checkBox_D1->TabIndex = 0;
this->checkBox_D1->Text = L"D1";
```

The only difference that I can find between the fourth DataGridView and the others that don't cause the problem is that three of them are inside a Group box and the fourth one is outside the Group Box.  I created all four DataGridView controls by copy and pasting from the first one.  I thought that might have caused the problem so I created the fourth one from scratch, but it didn't resolve the issue.  All four DataGridView controls call the same event handler and point to the same function.

I changed the name of Form1 to MainForm, but it still shows up as Form1 in some places.  Why is that, and is this causing this issue?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to provide an update.  I don't think the event is the source of the issue because the exception came back when I edited other controls on the form.  I can't pinpoint exactly what changes on the GUI cause the code builder to add the resource.  Some changes that caused the exception to come back:  deleting a control that I no longer want, deleting the toolTip, and even something as trivial as resizing the GroupBox that surrounds three of the DataGridView controls.  Weird!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by recreating the form.  It was faster to recreate the GUI and transfer all my code than to try to figure out how to fix it.  I'm going to guess that the project got hosed up, but I don't understand how Visual Studio organizes the resources well enough.